# Spring EL - Invoking static interface method

Tags: spring-el

Is there a way to invoke a static interface method in SpEL?
For example:

```
T(java.util.stream.IntStream).of(new Integer[]{1,2,3}).sum()
```

When I run this I get this error: `Problem locating method of on type class java.lang.Class`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are missing to show us more stack trace:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1033E: Method call of 'of' is ambiguous, supported type conversions allow multiple variants to match
at org.springframework.expression.spel.support.ReflectiveMethodResolver.resolve(ReflectiveMethodResolver.java:211)
```

It can't resolve a proper method at runtime via reflection, just because there are several `of()` method in the `IntStream`.

This works for me:

```
ExpressionParser parser = new SpelExpressionParser();
Expression expression = parser.parseExpression("T(java.util.stream.IntStream).of(1,2,3).sum()");

assertThat(expression.getValue()).isEqualTo(6);
```

Answer (score 2):

It needs to be `"T(java.util.stream.IntStream).of(new int[]{1,2,3}).sum()"`.

(`int[]` not `Integer[]`).

The problem is there are 2 `of()` methods and conversion is needed from `Integer[]` and so you get

> Caused by: org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1033E: Method call of 'of' is ambiguous, supported type conversions allow multiple variants to match

Comment: I opened a [JIRA issue about the misleading error message](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-16762).